# How would I get an object from a list of a custom class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a class called Student, it includes a name, and a few grades which don't matter too much for this issue. How would I select a single student by his name from a List object?

Comment: Do you know how to write a loop?

Comment: Like for, while etc? Yeah but I am not so familiar with the foreach loop.

Comment: So you have a list of objects of type student? and you want to pull one out based on the name property of the student class?

Comment: Correct, there is a string called name in student.cs

Comment: @dvs - if you're familiar with arrays or lists, basically all a `for each` loop does, is runs some code against each item within the collection (i.e. each item in the list, or array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == studentName);
```

Comment: So students is the list, studentname is a string, but what is s?

Comment: please google `lambda expression` and `linq query`

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Student> listOfStudents = new List<Student>();
// ...
// put some data to listOfStudents
// ...

var searchName = "MyName";
var singleStudent = listOfStudents.Single(s => s.name == searchName);
// or SingleOrDefault(s=>s.name == searchName)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing it. Simplest would be use a loop like:

```
List<Student> list = new List<Student>();
Student matchedStudent = null;
string inputStudentName = "SomeName";
foreach (var student in list)
{
    if (String.Equals(inputStudentName, student.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        matchedStudent = student;
        break;
    }
}

if (matchedStudent != null)
{
    //student found
}
```

You can also use **LINQ** and `FirstOrDefault` like:

```
matchedStudent = list.FirstOrDefault(s => String.Equals(inputStudentName, s.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

There are other LINQ methods to get a single object, like `Single`, `SingleOrDefault` etc.

If you want to get a collection of all students matching your criteria then you can do:

```
var matchedStudentCollection = list.Where(s => String.Equals(inputStudentName, s.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

It would be better to start off with loops and then read more about [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb397933.aspx), you would be able to write shorter and elegant code using LINQ.

Comment: Simplest is the best way forward for the op in this case, the one above is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start learning LINQ, you could start here: [Basic LINQ Query Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx).

```
var student = students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == searchName);
```

This expression is a "lambda expression":

```
s => s.Name == searchName
```

It's an anonymous function. It gets called for each item in the list. To make it a little clearer, you could write

```
(Student s) => s.Name == searchName
```

`s` is the parameter. Since `students` is `List<Student>`, the compiler can infer the type of the parameter.

In regular C#, you'd write it like this -- but with this kind of function definition, it has no way to access the local variable `searchName`, so you'd have to do something clumsy to make that work. A lambda expression can "see" all the local variables where it's defined, which simplifies everything.

```
function bool Predicate(Student s) {
    return s.Name == searchName;
}
```

FirstOrDefault may return null.

If you want to throw an exception on a missing student, or on redundant student names (both sound like a bad idea in the particular case of students), you can require exactly one match:

```
var student = students.Single(s => s.Name == searchName);
```

If there might be several and you want them all,

```
var studentEnumeration = students.Where(s => s.Name == searchName);
```

That'll return a query that you can loop through:

```
foreach (var student in studentEnumeration) {
    //  Rap each student on the knuckles with a ruler
}
```

Comment: I'd say it might be ill advisable to use single, on grounds that it's certainly valid for two people to have the same first and last name.

Comment: @user2366842 I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Let `StudentList` be a list of `students`(student objects), that you are maintaining through your codes. Consider you want to select First student based on his/her name. then you can use List[.FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909042(v=vs.90).aspx) which gives you the first matching student object that satisfies the given condition: if you need to fetch all the students whose name will be equal to the search text, the you can use List[.Where()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx)

```
List<student> StudentList = new List<student>();
//TODO: Populate the List here 

string searchName = "luckey";

student FirstStudent = StudentList
  .FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(searchName, 
                                     x.Name,
                                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

// first student whose name is luckey
List<student> searchResult = StudentList
  .Where(x => String.Equals(searchName, 
                            x.Name,       
                            StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  .ToList();
//sub list of students whose name is luckey
```